# how to assign and check event time of a message in apache beam

Tags: apache-beam

My source is a `KafkaIO.read()`, and now I want to use a ParDo, to decode the messages come from kafka, and use one field of the message as the event time of this message. How can I do it? I didn't find any example on how to do it.

Comment: Were you able to find out how to do this ? Please share your findings since I am currently facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

First You need to implement CustomTimestampPolicy, by extending `TimestampPolicy<KeyT,ValueT>`

For example:

```
public class CustomFieldTimePolicy extends TimestampPolicy<String, Foo> {


protected Instant currentWatermark;

public CustomFieldTimePolicy(Optional<Instant> previousWatermark) {
    currentWatermark = previousWatermark.orElse(BoundedWindow.TIMESTAMP_MIN_VALUE);
}


@Override
public Instant getTimestampForRecord(PartitionContext ctx, KafkaRecord<String, Foo> record) {
    currentWatermark = new Instant(record.getKV().getValue().getTimestamp());
    return currentWatermark;
}

@Override
public Instant getWatermark(PartitionContext ctx) {
    return currentWatermark;
}
```

}

Then you need to pass your custom TimestampPolicy, when you setting up your KafkaIO source using functional interface `TimestampPolicyFactory`

```
KafkaIO.<String, Foo>read().withBootstrapServers("http://localhost:9092")
                .withTopic("foo")
                .withKeyDeserializer(StringDeserializer.class)
                .withValueDeserializerAndCoder(KafkaAvroDeserializer.class, AvroCoder.of(Foo.class)) //if you use avro
                .withTimestampPolicyFactory((tp, previousWatermark) -> new CustomFieldTimePolicy(previousWatermark))
                .updateConsumerProperties(kafkaProperties))
```

This line is responsible for creating a new timestampPolicy, passing a related partition and previous checkpointed watermark see the [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.5.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/kafka/TimestampPolicyFactory.html#createTimestampPolicy-org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition-java.util.Optional-)

```
withTimestampPolicyFactory(tp, previousWatermark) -> new CustomFieldTimePolicy(previousWatermark))
```